# arcade sf2a: akuma Shun Goku Satsu

Tags: arcade, mame, street-fighter-series

I can pull akuma's Shun Goku Satsu (3special, lp, lp, r, lk, hp) easily on psx, but trying now on mame with a USB controller I got zero out of a thousand.

is this somewhat different to pull on the arcade and I simply suck at it? or should it be as easy on the arcade as it is on the psx and my setup is bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about **input**.

To pull of certain moves you need to do certain patterns within X frames from the first input. Things like this were a lot stricter in Street Fighter one where everything had to be frame perfect.

I don't know what USB controller you have, but, in games like Street Fighter, it's down to how well you can use that input. For instance, gimme an Xbox 360 controller and I'll pull of 720 spin moves pretty easily. Gimme a keyboard and watch me struggle to pull off single-rotation moves.

It'll take some adjusting and getting used to, but eventually, as you grow more comfortable with the USB controller, you'll pull off moves more consistently. Just give it more practice :)

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. It doesn't actually address the specific concern in the question, and comes off like it's trying to share the author's fun facts instead.